# How to apply formats in google charts simple method

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have seen a lot of answers on the web for this question but everybody have answered in a different way. They have answered with examples of code 90+ lines of code so it's hard to understand the method for applying formats. Can somebody please explain the method of applying formats in google charts and there are different methods for different types of charts? I need to apply the formats on bar charts and donut charts. I want to change format to currency and decimals.

```
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Marketplaces', 'Number Of Orders','Value of Order'],
```

```
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('sales_total_quantity'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to format the chart values, as shown when the bar or pie slice is hovered,
you need to apply a format to the data table.

you can use google's number formatter.

```
var patternCurrency = '$#,##0.00';

// format third column of data table
var formatCurrency = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
  pattern: patternCurrency
});
formatCurrency.format(data, 2);
```

if you also want the y-axis of the bar chart to show as currency,
you need to use config option --> `vAxis.format`

```
var optionsBar = {
  // format y-axis
  vAxis: {
    format: patternCurrency
  }
};
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Marketplaces', 'Number Of Orders', 'Value of Order'],
    ['A', 10, 100.11],
    ['B', 20, 200.22],
    ['C', 30, 300.33],
  ]);

  var patternCurrency = '$#,##0.00';

  // format third column of data table
  var formatCurrency = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: patternCurrency
  });
  formatCurrency.format(data, 2);

  var optionsBar = {
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'both'
    },
    // format y-axis
    vAxis: {
      format: patternCurrency
    }
  };

  var chartBar = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart-bar'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chartBar, 'ready', function () {
    // show tooltip
    chartBar.setSelection([{column: 2, row: 0}]);
  });
  chartBar.draw(data, optionsBar);

  var optionsPie = {
    height: 300,
    pieHole: 0.2
  };

  var chartPie = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart-pie'));
  chartPie.draw(data, optionsPie);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart-bar"></div>
<div id="chart-pie"></div>
```